# Websupergoo ABCPDF.NET - check if the pdf is encrypted/password protected before calling doc.Read()

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, abcpdf

doc.Read(filePath) will error out if the pdf file is encrypted and a password is not passed.  I haven't been able to find a way to check to see if the pdf document is encrypted before calling doc.Read() so I can better handle this occurrence.  Anyone know of a way?

Answer (score 1):

check the doc encrption type to be 2?

```
bool encrypted = false;
using (Doc theDoc = new Doc())
{
    XReadOptions options = new XReadOptions { ReadModule = MyPDF.Pdf };
    theDoc.Read(inputbytearray, options);
    if (theDoc.Encryption.Type == 2)
      encrypted = true;
}
```

Comment: That would be nice, but it seems Read() takes a password parameter that is expected for protected pdfs.  Exception is being thrown when calling Read():

`WebSupergoo.ABCpdf12.Internal.PDFException: PDF password is incorrect.     at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf11.XReadOptions.(Doc , String , XReadResult )     at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf11.XReadOptions.(Doc , String , XReadResult )     at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf11.XReadOptions.Read(Doc , String )     at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf11.Doc.Read(String path)`

Comment: you could catch that exception in a try catch then you will know